# Migration dependencies reference nonexistent parent node when trying to migrate after db change

Tags: python, django, postgresql, migration

Before, I used to keep the same db for development and production (postgresql). This isn't the greatest idea, so I made it so that the db I was currently using would only be used in production (and I'd have an sqlite db locally).

Well, I tried to migrate the production db and hot this traceback when trying to migrate at heroku:

```
(bosnetvenv) michael@michael-VivoBook-ASUSLaptop-MJ401TA:~/projects/znet/bosnet$ heroku run python manage.py migrate
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.35.0 to 7.38.1.
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ zealchain... up, run.1153 (Hobby)
/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
  """)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 335, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 79, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 267, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 241, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 243, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 243, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 96, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration engine.0003_auto_20200313_0826 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('powerdns_manager', '0007_auto_20200219_0300')
```

powerdns_manager is a package outside my app that I downloaded. Let me know if you need to see the migrations file. Thanks in advance

Edit: BTW, migrations work locally, and they worked in production when i was sharing the same db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update the remote repo (my fork of django-powerdns-manager)